# How can I display first 3 element instead of displaying all css only

Tags: html, css

I have code like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Karnataka</li>
<li>Assam</li>
<li>Gujarath</li>
<li>Westbengal</li>
<li>Karnataka</li>
<li>Assam</li>
<li>Gujarath</li>
<li>Westbengal</li>
<li>Karnataka</li>
<li>Assam</li>
<li>Gujarath</li>
<li>Westbengal</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to display only first three `li` elements.

Comment: Are you asking how to use `display: none` ? Or using `HTML` remove the `html`

Comment: no not that one. suppose i have 10 or more than that,in that i need to display first three only. How can i?

Answer (score 4):

To hide first three elements, first hide to all element and then exclude first three elements.

```
li { display: none; } /* Hide all */
li:nth-child(-n+3) { display: list-item; } /* Display first three */
```

Answer (score 0):

This css code may help you.

```
<style>
  ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  ul li:nth-child(1), ul li:nth-child(2), ul li:nth-child(3) {
    display: list-item;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in many ways.this is one of it and, one of the easiest way.what you have to do is, put your list into a `div`, then give it a `width` and `height`.
`height` should be only for your third `li` element.then `hide` others like this.
this is html and css for you.if you want you can use external css file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

 div.mylist{
  width:300px;
  height:70px;
  overflow: hidden;

 }

</style>
<body>

<div class="mylist">
  <ul>
    <li>Karnataka</li>
    <li>Assam</li>
    <li>Gujarath</li>
    <li>Westbengal</li>
    <li>Karnataka</li>
    <li>Assam</li>
    <li>Gujarath</li>
    <li>Westbengal</li>
    <li>Karnataka</li>
    <li>Assam</li>
    <li>Gujarath</li>
    <li>Westbengal</li>
  </ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

hope this will help to you. change the height according to your needs.

Comment: I only concerned about displaying the list items.It's probably working in browsers because browsers are too forgiving.but this is the standard.sorry for it @Paulie_D,  and I updated the answer.